# iOS - When a UIView appears on screen what method does it call?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, viewdidappear

When a UIView appears on screen what method does it call? 
For example if a have a UIScrollView and I populate it with a hundred views, one under the other,
what method is called by the UIViews when they are scrolled such that they appear on screen?

is it -(void)didMoveToWindow  ? something else ?

Comment: None. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to create a custom uiview subclass with a delegate that calls a delegate function when it appears on screen to the user

Comment: The view doesn't have that knowledge. Scroll views can tell you what area of their content they are currently making visible, but not automatically what subviews are in that area. The views know nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to find out when a view gets scrolled into scrollView bounds, it might be easier and probably more performant to use a table view... Table view has methods that let you know when a cell will appear and you can query visible cells at any time.

Comment: will / didMoveToSuperView are called when the subviews are added, not scrolled into view.

Comment: What Wain said is true

Comment: @Wain true, I got focused on "when it appears on screen" part of question. But like I said, go with table view...

Answer (score 1):

Specifically for a scroll view, the delegate (usually the controller) can get notified that the scroll view has scrolled. When you get this callback you can write a bit of code that iterates through the subviews and checks which are in the visible frame of the scroll view (using `CGRectIntersectsRect`, `contentOffset` and `bounds`).

Comment: Too much processing. Not smooth enough.

Comment: Scrollviews can be very long and have many subviews loaded on them.. I am aware that I could use a tableview to avoid such an overload but I am looking to see if the scrollview way is possible first

Comment: Generally speaking, there is no reason to have views that aren't visible loaded. So really you should be monitoring the scroll and loading as required (which is exactly what table views do).

Comment: @Filip states this in his answer so I will tick it as correct but I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

None, BUT if you implement the UIScrollView delegate the UIScrollView does call a method that gives you the scroll position and more (many methods, most likely scrollViewDidScroll).

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html

To see which view, you have to calculate which view is visible by seeing if CGRectIntersectsRect(scrollView.bounds, subview.frame) returns true.

Comment: Yes but it doesn't tell me which view came into visibility which is what i am looking for. Now I am aware that I could store them in an array and find our which one by iterating through their positions but that is too much processing and not smooth enough for what I need.

Comment: You have to calculate which view is visible. I've amended the answer